# How to store multiple color values and save them to UserDefaults - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults, nsattributedstring

I'm creating a rich text editor consisting of a textView with an attributed text that has two attributes, color and font style. These attributes are assigned to any range of selected text the user wants, and the text can have as many attributes of color and font as the user requires. The note should be saved to disk. I have managed to save to disk an load when launching one color, font and range attribute at the same time, now i'm trying to save as many color attributes as necessary, I don't know how to do this, so I came with the idea that I should store them in an array and save this array to disk. I have the following code:

```
func didSelectColorCell(color: UIColor) {
    noteTextView.setAttributedValueAtSelectedTextRange(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: color)
    let colors = [color].append(color)
    UserDefaults.standard.store(colors, forKey: "selectedColor")
    let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: noteTextView.selectedRange)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "selectedTextRange")
}
```

The above function is a method that conforms to a protocol of a delegate I created to pass the color value from another view controller.

This is the `storecolors:` function:

```
func store(_ colors: [UIColor], forKey key: String) {
    set(NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: colors), forKey: key)
}
```

The compiler shows an error:

> Cannot use mutating member on immutable value of type [UIColor]

How can I make the array a mutable value? Should I approach this in a different way (not storing the colors in an array)? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Use RGB values to store then while retrieving convert to `UIColor`.

Comment: try to use encode and decoder

Comment: just to focus solely on your question about mutability regarding function params. They get passed in as immutable objects. You can either make a copy `var colorsCopy = colors`, or mark the paramter with inout, indicating that you want it to be mutable`func store(_ colors: inout [UIColor]`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to encode a value passed through a delegate using NSCoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41360491/how-to-encode-a-value-passed-through-a-delegate-using-nscoding)

Comment: You did ask a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41360491/how-to-encode-a-value-passed-through-a-delegate-using-nscoding which I already post a sample to guide how to save object (including list if you can try yourself) into UserDefaults. Read the answer and comment what do you think.